# Data extraction from two tables with no common field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

By login to my Oracle schema PRODUCT, I run following two queries to get the required details:

**Query-1**: Find all the session numbers in PRODUCT schema where start date is before 01-Nov-2020.

```
select SESSION_NO, SESSION_BEG
  from APP_SESSION
  where SESSION_BEG < to_date('2020-11-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  order by SESSION_BEG;
```

**Query-2**: Find all the tables with their size in PRODUCT schema where table name consists of Session Number **357924160** which is one Session Number among many what I get from **Query-1** output.

```
select SEGMENT_NAME,
       BYTES/1024/1024 as "SIZE in MB"
  from USER_SEGMENTS
  where SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' and
        SEGMENT_NAME like '%357924160%'
  order by "SIZE in MB" desc;
```

As there is no common column between the two tables USER_SEGMENTS and APP_SESSION and there are many Session Numbers (in thousands) from Query-1 output to check, I have to run the Query-2 again and again for each Session Number.

I would like to know whether there any way in Oracle to Join query-1 and query-2 together to find all the tables with size where table name consists of any of the Session Numbers where start date is before 01-Nov-2020 ?

Comment: Show us some sample table and also the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
select ap.SESSION_NO,
       ap.SESSION_BEG,
       us.SEGMENT_NAME,
       us.BYTES/1024/1024 AS "SIZE in MB"
  from APP_SESSION ap
  INNER JOIN USER_SEGMENTS us
    ON us.SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND
       us.SEGMENT_NAME LIKE '%' || ap.SESSION_NO || '%'
  where ap.SESSION_BEG < to_date('2020-11-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  order by ap.SESSION_BEG,
           "SIZE in MB"
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting the result what I want. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
select SEGMENT_NAME,
       BYTES/1024/1024 as "SIZE in MB" 
from USER_SEGMENTS, APP_SESSION
where SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' and
      SESSION_BEG < to_date('2020-11-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
      SEGMENT_NAME like '%' || SESSION_NO || '%'
order by "SIZE in MB" desc;
```